# Convert decimal to hex with leading zeros using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I Wanted to convert 00017 to hex using oracle with leading zero's:

For Example:

```
**SELECT TO_CHAR(00017,'XXXX') FROM DUAL;**
```

Current Output of above query 11

But Expected output is with leading zero 00011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For padding zeros you have to add them to the pattern

```
select to_char(17, '0000X') from dual
```

In `000X` the `X` is the format specifier and the number of `0` determine the length.

Comment: On the above solution SELECT TO_CHAR(group,'000XX') FROM order giving ora-01722 invalid number where order is table and group is varchar2 column.

Comment: Well obviously, because the first parameter of `TO_CHAR` has to be a number or a datetime. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm Why do you store numbers in a varchar column? Oracle will try to convert the varchar to a number, but if the content of that specific row is not a valid number, it will throw an error

Comment: I need to select group column(varchar2) into hex with leading zeros. so I have tried to use SELECT TO_CHAR(group,'000XX') FROM order, but its giving error. is there any other way to select group column(varchar2) into hex with leading zeros?

Comment: at least one value in the group column is not a valid number. for instance null, or empty string, or containing characters check your data ...